# Simulate a excel formula in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, automation

I am trying to simulate a excel formula from past few hours but not unable to do so. Any help would be appreciated

Excel Version of the formula -

```
IF(N2<>N1,O2-L2,Q1-L2)

Explanation - IF (N2 != N1) THEN O2-L2 ELSE Q1-L2

Columns Abbreviations - 

N = key_2
O = available_inventory
L = total_demand
Q = net_inventory
```

I have done some initial steps in Python but not able to reproduce the same formula. Below is my version -

```
1. df_ao_pvt['key_2_shift'] = df_ao_pvt['key_2'].shift(-1,axis = 0)

2. df_ao_pvt['available_inventory'] = df_ao_pvt['available_inventory'].replace(np.nan, 0)

3. df_ao_pvt['net_inventory'] = df_ao_pvt.apply(lambda row: row.available_inventory - row.total_demand if row.key_2 != row.key_2_shift else row.net_inventory - row.total_demand, axis = 1)
```

Additional Information - DTYPE of the columns involved are written below -

```
1. total_demand - int64
2. key_2 - Object
3. available_inventory - float64
```

We need to create the formula in a new column called net_inventory (as written in Python version of the code). The populated column is net_inventory itself (as written in python code)

Below is the sample data format where I want to replicate the formula (Note - In actual data the rows are more than 1 million) -

```
total_demand|key_2|available_inventory|key_2_shift|net_inventory
120000|20611011205|120520611012019-06-19|240000|120520611012019-06-20|120000
120000|20611011205|120520611012019-06-20|120000|120520611012019-06-26|0
120000|20611011205|120520611012019-06-26|120000|120520611012019-06-27|0
120000|20611011205|120520611012019-06-27|0|280120611012019-06-20|-120000
180000|20611012801|280120611012019-06-20|0|310420611012019-06-06|-180000
```

Comment: Have a look at np.where

Comment: @QuangHoang  Can you help me to write the code? I am still getting the error.

Comment: isn't your `net_inventory` is just `available_inventory` - `total_demand` now?

Comment: Yes it is only for the sample data which I have shared but not always. There are many scenarios where the above calculations goes wrong

Comment: @QuangHoang Any help that you can provide to me as a solution for this!

Answer (score 0):

`np.where` is like `IF` in Excel. So you would want to do:

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['N'].ne(df['N'].shift()), 
                         df['O'], 
                         df['Q'].shift()
                        ) - df['L']
```

Replace `N,O,Q,L` with the respective column names.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Its showing me error. SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: The error got resolved now. But if you see my problem statement I am creating a new column which is column Q itself. So can you incorporate that in your solution? Right now I am getting the error KeyError : col Q

Comment: I now have some idea what you are trying to do. It would help if you can copy/paste several rows of your excel files to the questions (with the expected output).

Comment: Added the sample data in the description